# xpath preceding-sibling select

Tags: xpath, siblings

could someone give me a hint how to get "Some text1" in dependence on svg class="svg svg-goal"?

**This works**

```
$x("//br/../preceding-sibling::strong/a")
```

**This does not work**

```
$x("//svg[@class='svg svg-goal']/../preceding-sibling::span/strong/a")
```

Hier HTML code

```
<span class="event-p-name">
    <strong>
        <a href="">Some text1</a>
    </strong>
    <small>
        <br>Some text2</br>
    </small>
</span>
<span class="event-type">
    <svg class="svg svg-goal">
        <use xlink:href="/public/themes/svg/symbol-defs.svg#football"></use>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<svg>` element (and its child elements) you need to use `//*[name()='svg']` syntax. Try below:

```
//*[name()='svg' and @class='svg svg-goal']/../preceding-sibling::span/strong/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//svg[@class='svg svg-goal']/preceding::span/strong/a
```

Result

```
<a href="">Some text1</a>
```